# sql return categories ordered by blog post date

Tags: sql, blogs, categories, subquery

I've a Wordpress website with articles. A post can contain or more categories (table wp_terms). Now I want a query that returns a list of all term names, ORDERED BY the blogs article date. I have experimented with a SELECT in a SELECT query, but that doesn't work... How can I do it and return the categories ordered by the article date?

table **wp_posts** (as example):

```
|ID------|post_title------------------|post_date-|
|1       |Test title                  |2014-05-05|
|2       |Test title 2                |2014-04-01|
|3       |Last test title             |2014-02-02|
|4       |Another blog item           |2014-01-06|
```

table **wp_terms**:

```
|term_id|name---------|
|1      |computers    |
|2      |home         |
|3      |work         |
```

table **wp_term_relationships**

```
|object_id|term_taxonomy_id|term_order|
|1        |2               | 0        |
|1        |1               | 0        |
|2        |3               | 0        |
```

table **wp_term_taxonomy**

```
|term_taxonomy_id | term_id |
|1                |1        |
|2                |2        |
|3                |3        |
|4                |4        |
```

This is my current query, but this doesn't work right...

```
SELECT t.*, p.*  FROM wp_terms AS t 
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `ID`, `post_title`, max(`post_date`) as `date` FROM wp_posts
GROUP BY `ID` ) as p on p.`ID`= tr.`object_id` GROUP BY t.`term_id` ORDER BY p.`date` desc
```

Comment: Show us your query and expected output

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you are trying to achieve. But this is your query which runs without errors

```
SELECT t.*, p.* 
FROM wp_terms AS t JOIN wp_terms_taxonomy AS tt 
    ON tt.term_id = t.term_id 
JOIN wp_terms_relationship AS tr 
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id 
        = tr.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT ID, post_title, max(post_date) as date 
 FROM wp_posts 
 GROUP BY ID , post_title) as p on p.ID= tr.object_id 
GROUP BY t.term_id,t.name,p.id,p.post_title,p.date
ORDER BY p.date desc
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98eff/13)

Comment: This isn't working...
What I'll receive is a list of all categories (terms) ordered by de latest blog date...